# How to send ip from user to PDO/MSQLI in a login form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a from that its working just perfect and I wanted to add some things i wanted to add the ip addres of user to the table of that user

Example:

```
user123 id- 1 pass - qwuHs7AtcbjIn(encripted) ip_address - 127.0.0.0
```

I wanted it always when he logins to send hes current ip to the column ip_address

Here's the code

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user->redirect('dash.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
    $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
    $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];

    if($user->login($uname,$umail,$upass,))
    {
        $user->redirect('dash.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Dados inválidos";
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: can you add what's inside `$user->login()` function?

Comment: add what in expecific?

Comment: the query you are using

Comment: i think the query is in the dbconfig.php

Comment: no w8 i dont have any kind of query in dbconfig and the login.php so i have to make a query?

Comment: maybe open the file where the class `USER` is?

Comment: if im not wrong your code is from here.  http://cleartuts.blogspot.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html  :)

Comment: Have u used this getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')? if not please check with this.

Comment: How is this possibly related to MySQL? You just want to obtaint the client's IP address; storing it into the database is not a problem, is it?

Comment: because i have to connect the ip to the table to the column ip_address

Comment: yeah roullie its from cleartuts

Answer (score 0):

You can a get user's IP using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, just keep in mind that you can not always trust the value to be valid since the user can easily spoof it, using a proxy for example.

```
$uip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Also if you are going to save the IP to a database as a string, make sure you have space for at least 45 characters(IPv6).

Comment: yeah but im not being able to do it cloud u give me the codes for it=?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've been messing with this and came up with this - it's not working, but maybe with some help you guys can tell me what's missing here.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //I've added this
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user->redirect('dash.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
    $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
    $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];
    $uip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //I've added this
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth, the short answer is you want `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Having said that, it’s not really reliable.

Most users will be behind some sort of router/firewall that does Network Address Translation. The server will not actually see the client’s IP address, which is probably an internal IP address, but the router’s address. This is how a whole organisation can get away with a single IP4 address, which is not going to help you any.

If you are only interested in tracking a single session, you will find using a random cookie or PHP session will be much more reliable.